# SQL Server 2012 Setup Failure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am installing SQL Server 2012 in my computer but this error message always shows up. I tried installing it in a Virtual Machine, and it worked! Other threads says that the issue is permission access, but I've already allowed access and I'm using an admin account. I also tried cleaning up my temp folder files, nothing still. Hope someone could help me resolve this problem. Thanks!

PS. I am using Windows 10 Pro

`TITLE: SQL Server Setup failure.

SQL Server Setup has encountered the following error:

Unable to generate a temporary class (result=1).
error CS0016: Could not write to output file 'c:\Users\jdaquino\AppData\Local\Temp\mcxybaib.dll' -- 'The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. '

Error code 0x84B10001.`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9F0k.png)

Comment: Please, add the version of Windows you're using.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ProcMon](http://improve.dk/solving-access-denied-errors-using-process-monitor/) to identify the other process using the file.

[image]

My suggestion is to also change the default account that start the services to "Local System", to a local administrator account or to a domain account. Below the setup page where I suggest you to change the default service accounts.

[image]

Please follow [this](http://www.sqlcoffee.com/SQLServer2012_0007.htm) step-by-step tutorial on how to install SQL Server 2012.

Disable antivirus software.

Change the language of the operating system in Control Panel to English US (Control Panel - Region - Formats Tab - Format -> English (United States))

Comment: Hi. Thank you for responding. I tried to use the ProcMon but the file wasn't there. As for your second suggestion, I cannot even get to the Setup window, because every time I open the setup.exe, it displays that error message.

Additional info: The .dll file changes everytime that error shows up.

Comment: Do you have any Antivirus software installed on that computer. Could you please try to disable it or uninstall it?

Comment: I only have Windows Defender installed. I tried to disable it and run the setup.exe again. The result was still an error, but a different one. See link: https://imgur.com/a/X6u6wNM | BUT THEN, I run it the second time, and my original error message shows up again.

Comment: Change the language of the operating system in Control Panel to English US (Control Panel - Region - Formats Tab - Format -> English (United States))